# Speeding powershell script with large csv file up

Tags: powershell, csv

I am kinda new to powershell. Only be toying with it for a few days now and have written the below script to help search for multiple conditions in a csv file.  I wrote something similar in VB and it takes 2 days to process the csv file.  This powershell script takes about 6 hours to process 6500 machines and 9 policies.  What i am trying to do is look in Policy.csv for a computer from computers.csv and a policy from a list and report if the computer has it or not.

Policy.csv has 6 fields in the table that need to be in the final report with an additional field added for status of the policy.

Computers.csv has 2 fields in the table that are the computer name and the OU it is in.

Packlist.txt is just the list of the applications(policies) that are being looked for.

Edit:
Samples of the csv files are as follows

```
Policy.csv  
Device,Device DN,Group,Group DN,Policy Domain,Policy  
Comp1,OU=Here,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy1  
Comp1,OU=Here,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy2  
Comp1,OU=Here,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy3  
Comp2,OU=There,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy1    
Comp2,OU=There,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy2  
Comp2,OU=There,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy3  

Computer.csv  
Device,Device DN  
Comp1,OU=Here  
Comp2,OU=There  
Comp3,OU=AnyWhere  

Packlist.txt  
Policy1  
Policy3  

Result.csv  
Device,Device DN,Group,Group DN,Policy Domain,Policy,Status
Comp1,OU=Here,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy1,Entitled
Comp2,OU=There,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy1,Entitled
Comp3,OU=AnyWhere,,,,Policy1,Notentitled
Comp1,OU=Here,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy3,Entitled
Comp2,OU=There,Domain_app,OU=Here,Ou=Apps,Server1,Policy3,Entitled
Comp3,OU=AnyWhere,,,,Policy3,Notentitled
```

The code is:

```
$data=import-csv -path c:\packagestatus\policy.csv
$computers=import-csv -path c:\packagestatus\computers.csv
$policylist= (Get-content -path c:\packagestatus\packlist.txt)
$policycount = $Policylist.count
$computercount = $computers.count
$Policycounter = 1

foreach ($policy in $policylist) 
    {
    $Policy
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Processing $policyCounter of $policycount"
    $Data_temp = $data|where-object{$_."Policy Instance" -eq $policy}
    $computercounter = 1
    foreach ($Computer in $computers)
        {
        $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Processing Policy $policyCounter of $policycount and Computer $computercounter of $computercount"
        if ($data_temp|Where-Object{$_.Device -eq $computer.device})
            {
            $result = $data_temp|where-object{$_.Device -eq $computer.device}|Where-Object{$_."Policy Instance" -eq $policy}
            $result|Add-member -membertype Noteproperty -name Status -value Entitled
            $result|export-csv -path c:\packagestatus\result1.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
            }
        Else
            {
            $result1 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Device" -value $computer.device
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Device DN" -value $computer."Device DN"
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Group" -value $null
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Group DN" -value $null
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Policy Domain" -value $null
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Policy Instance" -value $Policy
            $result1|add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Status" -value NotEntitled
            $result1|export-csv -path c:\packagestatus\result1.csv -force   -NoTypeInformation -append
            }
        $computercounter++  
        }
    $policycounter++
    }
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Completed"
```

Comment: Ew, nesting ForEach lists, with append writes within the inner loop. I can imagine that this takes a long time. It would help a lot if you posted examples of your files in the question.

Comment: Use `Measure-Command` to find out which part of the script is the slowest point. Aim for the lowest hanging fruit first.

Comment: Ew is right.  You appear to be attempting a cartesian join between two relations, for a total of over 50K lookups.  At 10 lookups per second, that's going to be 5K seconds, a long, long, time.  If I were attempting such a thing, I would want a relational DBMS at my disposal. Even then, I would be looking for a bug in the requirements or a bug in my approach.  I would want a way to reduce the cartesian join to a relational join.  (I apologize for the relational-speak).

Comment: So you are trying to look for a computername in CSV1, find it in CSV2 and then make sure that CSV2 also has the policy names from CSV3?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician  Yes this takes a long time and I have updated with sample CSV files.  We are talking hundreds of thousands of lines in the policy.csv file,

Comment: @WalterMitty I thought about doing a small relationship DB, but am new to database structures and am unsure of my abilities at it.

Comment: @Luke I am looping through packlist to search the object created by importing the policy.csv to look for each line that has that policy.  I am then looping through that new list and searching to see if each computer in computers.csv is in there and recording the result into an exported csv.

Comment: @vonPryz I know what is taking the longest in the script already just not sure how to make it go faster.  I may just need to rethink how I am processing the data.  The whole Where-object search is what is slowing the whole thing down.  I was looking at hashtables, but they look to only support two columns and I need more then that.

Comment: Awesome! Give me a little to wrap my head around this and figure something out. I'm sure we can make this faster. Debating between regex matching and a complex Switch command to get rid of the nested For loops, and moving the writes outside of the loop should make it faster so it only accesses the drive for one large write rather than thousands of small Open/Write/Close's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this should run faster for you...

I start by making a function to create objects for a given computer name, DN, and policy that it's missing. Then I load up the data from the files. Next I make a regex string to match against for all of the policies that are in the `$Policylist`. I do the same for the computer list. Then I filter down the `$Data` array for only entries that are in the policy list and also in the computer list.

This will, hopefully, limit the data that we're dealing with, and I think that will be faster in general. Next I group it by device, and for each grouping I look for any missing policies, and run that list against the function, and any matching policies I add the 'Status' property and output that entry. This is all collected in the `$Results` array.

Once we process all the computers we have records for, we look for the computers that weren't in the list, and create a NotEntitled object for all policies, and all all those to the `$Results`.

Lastly we sort and output $Results. It would be faster to not sort it I suppose, but probably harder to read as well. Here's the code, let me know how it works out for you:

```psh
Function NotEntitled{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Device,
    [String]$DeviceDN,
    [String[]]$Pack
)
Process{
    ForEach($Item in $Pack){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Device' = $Device
            'Device DN' = $DeviceDN
            'Group' = $null
            'Group DN' = $null
            'Policy Domain' = $null
            'Policy' = $Item
            'Status' = 'NotEntitled'
        }
    }
}
}

$Data = import-csv -path c:\packagestatus\policy.csv
$Computers = import-csv -path c:\packagestatus\computers.csv
$Policylist = ,(Get-content -path c:\packagestatus\packlist.txt)

$PolicyReg = ($Policylist|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
$ComputerReg = ($Computers.Device|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

$FilteredData = $Data | Where{$_.Policy -match $PolicyReg -and $_.device -match $ComputerReg}

$Results = $FilteredData | Group Device | ForEach{
    $Device = $_.group
    $MissingPolicies = ,($Policylist | Where{$_ -notin $Device.Policy})
    If(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($MissingPolicies)){NotEntitled $Device[0].Device $Device[0].'Device DN' $MissingPolicies}
    $Device | ForEach{Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Status' -NotePropertyValue 'Entitled' -PassThru}
}

$CompList = $FilteredData | Select -ExpandProperty Device -Unique

$Results += $Computers | Where{$_.Device -notin $CompList} | ForEach{NotEntitled $_.Device $_.'Device DN' $Policylist}

$Results | Sort Device,Policy | Export-Csv c:\packagestatus\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I took your sample data, changed Comp1 Policy3 to Comp1 Policy4 (so that I could have a computer with only a partial policy set), and ran it and got these results output:

```psh
"Device","Device DN","Group","Group DN","Policy Domain","Policy","Status"
"Comp1","OU=Here","Domain_app","OU=Here,Ou=Apps","Server1","Policy1","Entitled"
"Comp1","OU=Here",,,,"Policy3","NotEntitled"
"Comp2","OU=There","Domain_app","OU=Here,Ou=Apps","Server1","Policy1","Entitled"
"Comp2","OU=There","Domain_app","OU=Here,Ou=Apps","Server1","Policy3","Entitled"
"Comp3","OU=AnyWhere",,,,"Policy1","NotEntitled"
"Comp3","OU=AnyWhere",,,,"Policy3","NotEntitled"
```

Comment: This works significantly faster. Only Issue I am having is that I can only search one policy at a time. It seams to be lumping them all together as one policy. I think it might because the actual policy names are more like Policy1_00_43 and the regex isnt readying them correctly.  It is readying them as Policy1\Policy2

Comment: I figured out the issue.  You have a erroneous , in on of the lines for the import for the packlist.txt it should have been '$Policylist = (Get-content -path c:\packagestatus\Packlist.txt)'  Thanks for all your help